# Compare Reuse Identifier Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to have a custom cell height for all of my cells in my UITableView. In this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I try this:

```
if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] reuseIdentifier] == @"imageCell")
```

As I have 3 different cells setup with different identifiers in my storyboard. However my app just crashes here with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing a string, so you should be using `isEqualToString:`

```
if ([[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"imageCell"])
```

Answer (score 0):

> (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

you are supposed to calculate the height for you row, not to get the Cell of your tableView.

In my opinion, in the lifeCycle of a TableView delegate, the 1st step (before allocating each UITableViewCell), the TableView delegate call heightForRowAtIndexPath for each row (**but at this moment, the UItableViewCell are not allocated**). The, in a 2nd step, the TableView call

> > (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> >     to create UitableView Cells.

Comment: So your saying that it crashes because I am trying to get a cell which doesn't yet exist?

Comment: heap and "==" to compare 2 NSSTring must be replace by isEqualToString method

Comment: Turns out using isEqualToString (while I understand is correct), the line still causes the app to crash.